# Non-puzzle, but more meta-ish questions about code-golf that aren't about using the site

Tags: discussion, meta

My impression is that meta sites are for questions about using the site. I asked [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31/methods-of-counting-characters-on-various-systems) to test out a meta-ish type question that was not a puzzle itself, but not about how to use the site either. Is it on-topic there, or should it come here?

Answer (score 4):

We've had one of the many (currently 8) *"Tips on golfing in Foo"* flagged for moderator attention, with the assertion that it should be on meta, but I'm not sure that we have a consensus as yet.

I've been happy with those question on the main site as Community Wikis.

I'd like to get some more input on this before invoking the the moderator power tools.

Comment: I agree they should stay on the main site, as CW.

Answer (score 2):

I'm half-half, but I think such questions could have their place on the main site. Meta sites are more about usage of the site, not about how to come up with better answers. Other examples I can think of:

- Is code golfing the practice of elegance or obfuscation? (5 on-topic votes on area51 proposal)
- Tools to automate the shortening of code
- I see a lot of code golf answers using X. What does this mean? (might be better suited to SO)

Comment: I think the first is offtopic (100% subjective).